# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Minequery::read()

Tags: php, class, undefined

I'm trying to use the Minequery class found [here](http://github.com/vexsoftware/minequery-php) on my website to get my server status (player list, online/offline status, etc). I've downloaded it and copied it over to my ftp, so there shouldn't be any errors that could've happened, such as I didn't copy the whole script or something.

When I try to run it, it says `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Minequery::read() in /home/somedir/public_html/minequery.class.php on line 45`

I will by laziness and because it's so much code not paste the whole minequery.class.php here, so here's a link: https://github.com/vexsoftware/minequery-php/blob/master/minequery.class.php
I've also erased the JSON and Socket function, because I suppose I don't need them if I'm not using them. It doesn't seem like anyone else has had this problem, so don't come here and tell me to google it.

I'm also using the function to print the query that comes with the minequery usage.php page, i.e
`require('minequery.class.php');

print_r(Minequery::query("my-ip-goes-here"));`

Comment: So you're telling us you removed the methods `query_json()` and `read()`?

Comment: I removed the json method, because I don't use it, but not the read()... its still there, if you mean this: `$response = $class::read($address...`.

Comment: protected static function read, members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself.

Comment: @axel.michel `read()` is called within the class so there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @chrinsen I tried it on localhost and it worked fine without any problems `print_r(Minequery::query("109.230.238.205","25674"));`

Comment: @chris I've set up an example on my website, http://craftersinn.net/minequery.php Now it also takes forever to load...

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script.

Comment: hmm.. i included the minequery.class.php from github, now it doesn't take forever to load, but still doesnt show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments you stated that you removed the read method. Unfortunatelly, this method is called on any socket action including query(). So put the method back.

Here is the method called on query:

```
$response = $class::read($address, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, $write, $latency);
```

It is defined on line 123.

Comment: Yeah I realized it firstly after, and tried to edit the post, but I haven't enough rep yet... I've flagged the question for moderator review.